# How to change the data-href in Facebook Comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sdk, facebook-comments

How to change the `data-href` after loaded page and initialized the JS SDK.

I load the comments from the home page and want to new comments belong to the current page.

I tried this code jQuery, and `data-href` replaced good, but still new comments belong to the home page:

```
$('.fb-comments').on( "mouseover", function(){
    $(".fb-comments").attr("data-href", window.location.href);
});
```

Comment: not sure what you are asking. could you please elaborate what you are trying to do ?

Comment: what part do not you understand?

Comment: The SDK only goes through your document once on initialization – if you change the DOM afterwards, you need to call [`FB.XFBML.parse`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) to make it go through your document again.

Comment: I do not want to reload the comments SDK.
I want user to see the old comments, but his new comment to appear on a new page.